# Searching Math Symbols as Text: Mission Impossible?

Tags: symbols, text-formatting

How could the math types being represented in a format that are searchable like text?

I mean that there is a toolbar that you can have input math symbols and search for them as text, so the format can represent math symbols as text.

Is it such a task impossible to implement because math types can be represented only as icons?

What do you think is the proper implementation of a new format that loads symbols in memory like text-format?

Are there any existing solutions of searchable Math symbols in pdf or in any other format?

(I do not take under consideration Latex since you should use words for searching but not using math symbols directly and using words for searching a long Math formula could be very complex for writing down and the user could prefer to scroll the document than writing the whole latex-format of the math type)

**Designing new fonts that represent Math symbols can help of solving the problem or not at all?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If Latex is not good enough as an input method, how would you input your search query? Using a toolbar?

Comment: What do you mean by "using words for searching instead of using math symbols directly"? Searching for `one plus two` should match `1+2`?

Comment: You're essentially describing an image search, like OCR.  If you can constrain the number of symbols to a very small set, and provide scaling on the target images, an algorithm like OCR should be very accurate.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of what you mean? Math symbols are usually single letters with embellishments like subscripts, superscripts etc. Even if they were rendered as searchable text in a PDF, you'd get a lot of spurious results. (e.g. if you search for a mathematical symbol "a", you'll get more hits than you can handle).

Comment: @ Matti Virkkunen: Instead of the word "integral" to have as input the symbol of the integral for searching.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html ? Eg. a more portable version of that?

Comment: @Cam - incrediman: I would prefer that it is not a stochastic process but as determenistic as finding text.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem for musical notation. It was almost impossible to search for more obscure markings found in baroque music.

Our solution was to create a mapping table using SQL (SQL Server 2012) and then create xref tables as needed for the implementing products. This became necessary for some of the tablets that the music schools (mainly in the Northwest oddly) that had significantly different requirements.

Good luck